# How to map two objects into an array of objects in Angular?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects:

```
const object1 = {key: value, key2: value2};
const object2 = {key: value, key2: value2};
```

How to map both of them into an Array of objects? I red that I need to use **rxjs** operators, but I'm not sure.

Expected result:

```
[
    {
      object1
    },
    {
      object2
    }
]
```

Comment: What is that expected result ? And no, you don't need RxJS at all.

Comment: The expected result is one array, which has both of the objects inside.

Comment: `[object1, object2]`?

Comment: `array = [object1, object2]` ?

Comment: You're both right.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rxjs nor angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query:

```
const object1 = {key: value, key2: value2};
const object2 = {key: value, key2: value2};
```

try

```
// to insert more objects if required
const arr = [];
arr.push(object1);
arr.push(object2);
```

or

```
const arr = [object1,object2];
```

Answer (score 0):

With following data:

```
const object1 = {key: value, key2: value2};
const object2 = {key: value, key2: value2};
```

It is as easy as:

```
const arr = [object1,object2];
```